# Not proper UI while writing a responsive website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I constructed a similar UI as shown in this picture:
[image: img]
My work is in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akulkarni143/4om2s9u7/)
Here is a part of my code:

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #header {
        background-color: #125e9a;
        height: 7%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

In picture, both left list and right list are perfect. However in my code, both left  list and right list aren't as shown in the picture.
Here is a screen shot of my code:
[image: img]
The list in right is messed up, I went through the code, but couldn't fix it. Can you provide me good ideas to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by messed up? How would you like it to look like?

Comment: Well... check the picture and jsfiddle, you'd understand it.

Comment: Ajay. what is messed up? Can you point out?

Comment: If you are trying to match the image you provided exactly then there are plenty of things messed up as far as I can see... if you can be more specific, tell us what is wrong and tell us what you have tried to fix the issue so far we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not specified float for the first category, it acts as a block and occupies full width. Apply float: left to the left column category to align it.

```
.ctg {
  float: left;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Float: Left]